# GA4 custom events are not unique with measurment protocol

Tags: measurement-protocol, google-analytics-4

I have no problem when i try updating event count for purchase but as soon as i try changing with other event for example: "name":"event_name" the count is no more unique and it gets counted multiple time for same transaction_id which is not how it supposed to work. I see no documentation for such condition. Any help for this will be appreciated.

This works absolutely fine

```
{
  "client_id": "1772232177.16836XX647",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "purchase",
      "params": {
        "transaction_id": "RXXMCGX4HC"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But this will update the count for the same transaction id multiple times.

```
{
  "client_id": "1772232177.16836XX647",
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "comm_Lead",
      "params": {
        "transaction_id": "RXXMCGX4HC"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```